# Is it possible to stop execution of a test method after one iteration of DataProvider and not run all the iterations? If yes , How?

Tags: api, automation, testng, testng-dataprovider

Basically i want to run a test which will set certain value for a variable which i am going to use in another test(dependent). But the first method has DataProvider for over 30 iterations. I do not want to run it 30 times but only very first time.

Is it possible that i can terminate execution of the first method just after first iteration. 
Not sure but i believe Test Listeners can handle this but don't know how.
Anyone having any idea , please share your thoughts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the code of the `dataprovider` method to pass in a `Method` argument to it. This will be automatically be injected with the method about to invoked by testng. Place a if condition on the method name to return an `Object[][]` with **size of 1**.

```
@DataProvider(name = "provider")
  public Object[][] dp(Method m) {
      if(m.getName().equals("oneData")) {
          //Create and return object[][] SIZE 1
      } else {
         //Normal dump of data
      }
  }
```

Refer to this -- http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependency-injection